# Carregar paginas sem imagens e css no PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, desempenho, extensão, phantomjs

Alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer o carregamento mais rápido de uma página utilizando o phantomjs...

Pois tenho um Bot que percorre determinadas páginas através de paginação, no entanto preciso de uma forma para melhorar o tempo de carregamento dessas páginas para assim ganhar tempo.

**O site específico utiliza uma proteção contra BOTS (PerimeterX) que bloqueia file_get_contents e scrapper com PHP

Comment: Eu acho que o seu problema não está relacionado à uma linguagem ou extensão específica. Pois, as linguagens em geral conseguem armazenar o html de uma página de forma bem rápida. A sua limitação maior é a velocidade que o servidor do site selecionado gera o html e a banda deste servidor.

Comment: Tipo, com o php você usa o `file_get_contents(url)` ... Essa função só terminará de ser executada assim que ela obtiver o retorno do site. Se o site demorar mais 2 segundos para retornar a resposta, a sua aplicação irá demorar no mínimo 2 segundos de execução. Não importa qual linguagem ou extensão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa encontrei a solução aqui: 
https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-increase-web-scraping-speed-using-puppeteer/

Basicamente, é esse trecho de código que aponta os parâmetros de remoção de fonts, css e images.

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', (req) => {
    if(req.resourceType() == 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() == 'font' || req.resourceType() == 'image'){
        req.abort();
    }
    else {
        req.continue();
    }
});
```

Espero que ajude a quem possa precisar.